# OnDrop event on droppable divs?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to make drag/drop navigation creator menu on my custom CMS. 
I would like to create a callback function for this event.

1. There are 3 links in div `#links` (just `<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>`)
2. There is a div called div `#dropzone`.

I would like to have a callback function like this:

```
$.("#dropzone").onDrop(function() { alert "Callback"; });
```

How can I do this using HTML5 (if any new features about dropping exists) and jQuery? Once I get the callback, I can do the rest myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use draggable feature provided by jQuery UI. It has the stop event which fires when the dragging of the element is stopped. Go through the following link
[http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/][1] for more details. see the events tag for the events available.

Comment: jQuery UI seems like an external framework. Don't want to use this at this time. Can't I do this with basic jQuery? All I need is a callback when the target reaches destination, or stops so I can move target back to it's place.

Comment: Its not a separate UI framework. Its part of jQuery. Just u need to add one js file jQuery-ui.js thats it.

Comment: It *is* a separate framework, as to: not core jQuery. I, for one, am looking at how to do this without the overhead of adding jquery-ui.

Answer (score 2):

I just got this working with my project.  The key for me was telling the browser that `#dropzone` accepts drop events using the `dragover` event handler:

```
$("#dropzone").on("dragenter", function () {
    $(this).addClass("drop-allowed");
});
$("#dropzone").on("dragleave", function () {
    $(this).removeClass("drop-allowed");
});
$("#dropzone").on("dragover", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    return true;
});
$("#dropzone").on("drop", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    // Handle drop event here.
});
```